# Retaining Nuget packages published by pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

If I retain a release, will that also retain any NuGet packages published by that pipeline?

We have build pipelines for multiple versions of our product and each pipeline publishes about 10 NuGet packages.

When we get to a milestone on a particular version, we can retail that release.

I know it possible to promote individual packages to a Release, but its a very manual process to find the correct version of the 10 packages.

Answer (score 0):

> If I retain a release, will that also retain any NuGet packages published by that pipeline?

The answer is yes.

If we manually retain a release, **neither the pipeline's retention policy nor the maximum limits set by the administrator are applied** when you mark an individual run or release to be retained indefinitely. It will remain until you stop retaining it indefinitely.

You could check the [Q&A in this thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/retention?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#if-i-mark-a-run-or-a-release-to-be-retained-indefinitely-does-the-retention-policy-still-apply) for some more details.